# If-Condition, when i want to find out that the element is existing

Tags: java, xml

I guess its a really simple question, but i'm arent able to figure it out.

i try to write that when the element "composite" is existing that java adds attributes to it.

```
if() 
{
Element composite = doc.getRootElement(); 

composite.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance");

composite.setAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "v1_6.xsd");
}
```

Comment: `Element composite = doc.getRootElement(); if(composite != null) { ... }`

Comment: I don't quite get what your problem is. Are you after `composite != null`?

Comment: Are you looking for `if (doc.getRootElement() != null)` ?

Comment: my plan is that the following code is triggerd whit an if condition when composite is the RootElement.

Comment: I think your plan should be to study a good tutorial about the APIs you intend to use. Your question gives the impression that you don't have much knowledge about the things you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for,

```
Element composite = doc.getRootElement(); 
if(composite != null) 
{
    composite.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
    instance");

    composite.setAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "v1_6.xsd");
}
```